# How to add an email this page button in php

Tags: php, email, button

So I'm using buddypress on my wordpress page and would like to add an "email the current page" to the profiles.
I have  tried this code:

```
function my_custom_button() {
    //your button here
echo ' <br/><div class="mcb"><a href="mailto:?subject=Check out this page&body=$currentpage" title="">EMAIL THIS     PROFILE</a><div> ';
}
add_filter( 'bp_before_member_header_meta', 'my_custom_button' );
```

However, this does not put the URL of the current page in the body of the email. I have done a lot of research and found some other code which does return the url of the current page but can't seem to combine them:

```
$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
echo '<a href="' . $escaped_url . '">' . $escaped_url . '</a>';
```

Is there any way to make this work in an email?
I'm stuck at the moment and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all PHP doesn't resolve variables in single quotes. You'd have do concatenate multiple string parts with

```
'string part one ' . $my_variable . ' string part two'
```

In WordPress you can get the URL to the current page with `get_permalink()`

So your result should look like this:

```
function my_custom_button() {
    //your button here
     echo ' <br/><div class="mcb"><a href="mailto:?subject=Check out this page&body=' . get_permalink() . '" title="">EMAIL THIS     PROFILE</a><div> ';
}
add_filter( 'bp_before_member_header_meta', 'my_custom_button' );
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not put the current url into the body of my email at all even after I copy pasted your result into my functions.php. Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually the part about the resolving variables really helped and I got it to work with this ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '

Comment: Thank you for explaining that part to me and seeting me on the right path.